# isundoing and isredoing for NSUndoMananger are not available in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

isundoing and isredoing for NSUndoMananger are not available in OS X 10.10 or Swift. Do you have any suggestions for replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties are called `undoing` and `redoing` in Swift:

```
if undoManager.undoing {   }
if undoManager.redoing {   }
```

See [`undoing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUndoManager/undoing)
in the NSUndoMananger class reference.